# Siegel's Lemma for two solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

Consider the homogeneous diophantine equation
$$ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=0$$
over $\mathbb{Z}$ with a, b, c coprime.

(A version of) Siegel's Lemma states, that there exists a non-trivial solution $x$, such that
$$\max(|x_i|) \leq \sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}. $$
Another version states, that there exist two non-trivial linear independent solutions $x, y$, such that 
$$\max(|x_i|) \max(|y_i|) \leq \sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}. $$

Now suppose I already have a solution $x$, which satisfies the first inequality. Can I infer the existence of a second solution and bound it using the second inequality with the $\max(|x_i|)$ value of the first solution?

Comment: I understand now that you do not want your solution $(x_i)$ to be assumed coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So perhaps this is a counterexample you are looking for?

Take the equation
$$4x_1 + 5x_2 + 9x_3 = 0.$$
We have a solution $x = (3,3,-3)$ which satisfies $\max|x_i| \leq 122^{1/4} \approx 3.68$.

The next linearly independent solution of smallest height seems to be $y = (6,-3,-1)$, but
$$\max|x_i| \max|y_i| = 3 \cdot 6 = 18 > \sqrt{122} \approx 11.04.$$

Comment: Well, I don't want to assume that the known solution is coprime. I understand the simple construction of guaranteeing a solution via the pigeonhole principle, I don't know how guaranteeing the second solution works. Thus the question

Comment: The smallest linear independent solution is (5,-4,0). But the counterexample still works. I'm happy ;)